# Best way to optionally cache responses in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, caching, laravel-8

I'm building a Laravel API and i was wondering what the best method is for optionally caching responses?

Assuming i have the following UserController in my API:

```
public function index()
{
    return Cache::remember('users', '3600', function() {
        return new UserCollection(User::all());
    });
}
```

Now let's say in my app front-end that i want to force a refresh just in case there has been an update to the users within the past hour and i do not want to wait 1 hour for the cache to empty. How can i force a cache refresh and query the users from the database rather than the cache without waiting for the cache to expire?

One thought i had was to pass an additional header and use Middleware to retrieve the uncached resource but i'm not sure on this idea.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Make a button that causes `Cache::forget` to be executed with the same key (`users`).

Comment: Well damn, i never thought of that.

Thank you! That makes sense :)

Comment: Would that feature be "per request"? You make _one_ specific request that isn't cached but the cache should remain?

Comment: Calling `Cache::forget` would remove the item from the cache altogether, so i don't think it would be "per request", therefore any subsequent request would force it load from the database again. But in my situation this works for me and i'm okay with that as it's only used to power a simple admin dashboard used by a couple users.